# POST Request Using fetch() Returns 204 No Content

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, fetch-api

I'm making a POST request to a node.js server and I'm having trouble getting it to work. Here's my request:

```
const headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'this-can-be-anything',
};

export const postVote = (id, vote) =>
  fetch(`${uri}/posts/${id}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers,
    body: JSON.stringify({options: vote}),
  }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => data)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

The function accepts an 'id' and a 'vote', both strings. The id is being used as part of the URI in the request, and the vote is being supplied as options so the API knows what to do with it. Both of the arguments are being passed correctly:

```
id = '8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd'
vote = 'upVote'
```

Here's a link to the GitHub repository for the server/API:

[Udacity Readable API](https://github.com/udacity/reactnd-project-readable-starter/tree/master/api-server)

and a screenshot of the network when firing the request:

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE**: Added the second screenshot which shows status 200. Though it shows this and appears to have been successful, it still doesn't post to the server and the information stays the same.

Comment: Looks like the docs specify the param as `option` and you are sending it as `options`. Can you show us the response tab? Updated answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are looking at is the `OPTIONS` request in the network tab. For cross origin requests, every request if preceeded by an `OPTIONS` request which tells the calling client (browser, for example) if those HTTP methods are supported by the remote server for use in crosss origin context.

Check the other requests out. If the `OPTIONS` request was responded to correctly by the server, the browser must automatically follow up with your `POST` request

EDIT:
Also, the docs specify the param name to be `option` whereas in your screenshot it is coming up as `options`.

Further reading: [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: Good eyes to notice that.

Comment: Just as you were sharp with the `OPTIONS` request tab, you had an eagle eye for the docs as well. With that catch, everything works as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try declaring the headers as such:

```
var headers = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'this-can-be-anything',
})
```